# Shimano front-derailleur with 28.6 Clamp

Tags: shimano, derailleur-front, clamp

For my new Shimano M780 based gear I need a pull down (or bottom pull) front derailleur with a 28.6mm clamp for a 3x10 without direct mount. All the derailleur I have checked do not have a 28.6mm clamp. Are there not produced anymore? And if so, what would be the solution?

Comment: get a 30.1mm and get a shim like this one https://www.ebay.com/itm/Shimano-Ultegra-6600-6603-28-6mm-Front-Derailleur-Clamp-Shim-/192391026124

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can buy a braze on derailleur of the type you need and get a Braze on to 28.6 adapter. Alternately, you can get a derailleur with a larger size and get a shim. Either will be perfectly functional. Very few Mountain Bikes have 28.6 downtubes anymore so the likelihood of finding a 28.6 seems pretty low.